# java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 error

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to insert data in a table, but it shows the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I've searched this error and I tried all solutions but still it can't get it to work. Here's my code :

class.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Class</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
         <form method="post" action="class.jsp">
            <center>
                <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="5">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Enter Information Here</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
            <tr>
                        <td>Class Name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Class Strength</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="strength" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Room</td>
                        <td>
                           <input type="text" name="room" value=""> 

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Section</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="section" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
                    </tr>

            </tbody>
                </table>
            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

class.jsp

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*"  import= "java.sql.Connection"
%>
<%
    String cname = request.getParameter("name");
    String cstrength = request.getParameter("strength");
    String croom = request.getParameter("room");
    String csection = request.getParameter("section");

    //String available = request.getParameter("bavailable");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web",
            "root", "");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    //ResultSet rs;
    int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into class(name, strength ,room, section) values ('" + cname + "','" + cstrength + "','" + croom + "','" + csection + "', CURDATE());");
    if (i > 0) {
        //session.setAttribute("userid", user);
        response.sendRedirect("wel.jsp");
       // out.print("Registration Successfull!"+"<a href='index.jsp'>Go to Login</a>");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
%>
```

Comment: You should be using prepared statements to prevent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: BTW how is HTML code related to the SQL server error?

Comment: Please learn how to use prepared statements with parameters. **Do not** concatenate values into you query string. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query that you're running:

```
insert into class(name, strength ,room, section) values ('" + cname + "','" + cstrength + "','" + croom + "','" + csection + "', CURDATE());")
```

you've mentioned 4 column values to be passed (`class(name, strength ,room, section)`), but then you're passing in 5 values (an extra value for CURDATE())

Either add that new column in the table and update the query to include that column as well (i.e. (`class(name, strength ,room, section, curdate)`)) OR remove CURDATE().

Comment: i add another column name "regdate" and type "date" but still that error is appearing

Comment: did you update the code too to say `class(name, strength ,room, section,regdate)`?

Comment: yes  Sourabh Mahajan i updated my code

Comment: ok. please try taking this whole thing `"insert into class(name, strength ,room, section, regdate) values ('" + cname + "','" + cstrength + "','" + croom + "','" + csection + "', CURDATE());"` as a variable, print it, and run it directly on mysql studio. i'm pretty sure that the error, if at all it still comes, should not be about mismatching count.

Comment: i have another file of same code but different database name and values that file works fine i don't know why this file is not working

Comment: please print the query that's finally constructed and update here. that should  confirm the state.

Comment: your last code is working fine thank you so much brother i am working on this since morning

Answer (score 1):

Your input statement has four columns listed — `name`, `strength`, `room`, `section` — and then provides five values: `cname`, `cstrength`, `croom`, `csection`, and `CURDATE()`.

You just need to add the other column in the insert statement.

Comment: i add another column name "regdate" and type "date" but still that error is appearing

Comment: once you add the column, you need to adjust your query: `insert into class(name, strength ,room, section, regdate) values ('" + cname + "','" + cstrength + "','" + croom + "','" + csection + "', CURDATE());`

Comment: i tried this but still same error is appearing